# Slow load time after Rails upgrade to 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Has anyone noticed an exponential difference in load times after upgrading to Rails 3.1. It's taking ~4 seconds to load a very basic request on my local development machine. Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this - suspect it's something to do with Rails new asset pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/wavii/rails-dev-tweaks.

Rails is running all of the to_prepare hooks on every Sprockets asset request in development mode.  This includes things like auto-(re)loading your code, and various gems sneak work in there too.

rails-dev-tweaks disables to_prepare & reloading on any asset request (and a few others - read the first part of its README).  Speeds up your dev environment by a huge amount for any decently sized project.  It's also configurable to do this for any additional requests you like

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Passenger, then one reason for the slowdown is that all assets are now served by the asset pipeline, instead of the webserver (Apache/nginx). The former is far slower than the latter.

Also, in development Rails usually handles requests one at a time, so if you have many images on the page the slowdown is very noticeable.

Comment: It's also good idea to set config.assets.debug = false in development.rb so that rails doesn't request all of your css and js files individually.

Answer (score 0):

my idea would be (and i'd like to pack it into a gem, as soon as possible) to split up the development environment into frontend and backend development environments:

frontend:
  - cache classes
  - compile & serve assets on-the-fly
  - use for javascript + css

backend:
  - precompile assets (e.g. on server start)
  - reload classes etc on every request

you can do this basically by adding a forth file to `config/environments` with the appropriate config statements, but you have to restart your server when you switch between frontend and backend work

Answer (score 0):

My app is on Rails 3.0 so I can't speak to changes in the loading speed, however, I highly recommend using the [rails-dev-boost](https://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost) gem. It significantly speeds up application load time in development, making it pretty close to Production speed.

Make sure you read the installation instructions since it's a bit different than simply adding `gem 'rails-dev-boost` to your Gemfile.